# FFMpeg add text to actual video file after recording in Android

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, javacv

Am recording a video in Android device using JavaCV and playing it using a videoview. Now want to show a text on video while playing, which is entered after recording video. This text must be seen in all video players while playing the video.

I have gone thro the link [How to add text on video recording?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660443/how-to-add-text-on-video-recording) too which is expected here too

This is the method called after the video is recorded.

```
private void playRecordedVideo(Uri videoUri, boolean playVideoInLoop)
{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

    videoView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    videoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    videoView.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    if(playVideoInLoop)
    {
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener (new OnPreparedListener() {                    
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        videoView.setMediaController(null);
    }
    videoView.start();
    btnStart.setText(getString(R.string.txt_finish));
}
```