# Converting FrameLayout to Video?

Tags: android, view, android-videoview, android-framelayout

In my Framelayout I have an **ImageView and TextView** and I was able to convert the FrameLayout into a Bitmap and Save it by using the following snippet code

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameLayout.getWidth(), frameLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        frameLayout.draw(canvas);
        try {
             FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + path));
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream); 
}
```

Now I want to achieve the same behavior with my VideoView. So I have another FrameLayout with **VideoView and TextView** and I want to convert that FrameLayout into a VideoView so the TextView is incorporated inside the Video. 
I am wondering if it is possible and any ideas are welcome..

Edit 1: My .xml content

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/surface_camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/buttonstart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Username"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" /></FrameLayout>
```

Comment: can you please share code for framelayout with videoview and textview.

Comment: @NiravBhavsar I just added...

Comment: so what do you want from above ? do you want bitmap image of whole above relativelayout ?

Comment: @NiravBhavsar it should be inside FrameLayout. So just as I was able to save the FrameLayout of an **ImageView and TextView**  into a bitmap on my phone. I want to do the same thing too so my New FrameLayout which contains **VideoView and Textview** can be saved into one Video. (the Textview being inside the new video saved)...

Comment: taking video with text is a part of FFMPEG i think, please have a look in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641280/how-to-add-text-to-the-video-in-android)

Comment: thanks I will take a look @NiravBhavsar

Comment: @AmazingThing did you find a solution to convert your framelayout to video and save it