# Add text labels in video output file using camera2 API

Tags: android, renderscript, android-camera2, textureview

My goal is to add some text info in the video output file obtained after recording a video with the `Camera2 API` (e. g. date/time, user id etc.). I have checked some references about how to do this using `camera API` but I didn't find any information about how to do achieve this with `Camera2 API`. Can anyone help me?

[This is what I found for camera API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519235/modifying-camera-output-using-surfacetexture-and-opengl)

Comment: You want to add it over the output video? Like a video with a text in the right corner(as a watermark) or just as information inside the video metadata?

Comment: @FranciscoDurdinGarcia as a watermark

Comment: Then check my answer

Comment: try to read .hope this will give you some idea about it .![Check out this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660443/how-to-add-text-on-video-recording)

Comment: FFMPEG can help you

Answer (score 2):

The link that you provided about how to achieve your solution using Camera API will work also for `Camera2 API`. You should generate a `GLSurfaceView` with the information that you want to achieve together with a `GLSurfaceView.Renderer` to process each frame of your camera with `OpenGL`.

After configure your surface you should generate a new `Surface` from your `SurfaceTexture`:

`Surface videoSurface = new Surface(surfaceGLTexture);`

After that  you can use `createCaptureSession` together with your `Surface` and a `CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback()`to generate a video preview using `CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD` in your `CaptureRequest.Builder`.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [grafica](https://github.com/google/grafika). Take a look specifically at [TextureMovieEncoder.java](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/f3c8c3dee60153f471312e21acac8b3a3cddd7dc/src/com/android/grafika/TextureMovieEncoder.java). Replace the code in `private void drawBox(int posn)` with the code found in the best answer to this question:
[Draw text in OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es)
copied here for reference:

```
// Create an empty, mutable bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
// get a canvas to paint over the bitmap
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
bitmap.eraseColor(0);

// get a background image from resources
// note the image format must match the bitmap format
Drawable background = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
background.setBounds(0, 0, 256, 256);
background.draw(canvas); // draw the background to our bitmap

// Draw the text
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
textPaint.setTextSize(32);
textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
textPaint.setARGB(0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
// draw the text centered
canvas.drawText("Hello World", 16,112, textPaint);

//Generate one texture pointer...
gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
//...and bind it to our array
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

//Create Nearest Filtered Texture
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

//Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

//Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

//Clean up
bitmap.recycle();
```

Answer (score 0):

The same approach works, pretty much - the camera2 API wants a Surface to draw to, but you can create one from a SurfaceTexture:

```
Surface s = new Surface(mSurfaceTexture);
```

Then you can pass this Surface to the camera2 CameraDevice.createCaptureSession() call; see for example [Camera2Video](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) for a basic recording app to modify.

From your GL rendering, you have to then send the data to a video encoder.

Answer (score 0):

FFMPEG provides too many thing that you can do what you want. Please try this tool. May be it will help you. I suggest you. Please check this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38299320/3992798